# Xero API udpate a tracked item

Tags: xero-api

I'm trying to use Xeor api to update a tracked item, i used their **api.explorer** and another python library to update it but it doesn't work, it always shows a validation error as follows:

`"ValidationErrors": [ { "Message": "The COGSAccountId account is invalid." }, { "Message": "The InventoryAssetAccountId account is invalid." }, { "Message": "Cannot change Inventory Asset Account once item is tracked." }, { "Message": "The item cannot be made un-tracked because it is associated with tracked transactions" }`

It might be one of the error that is occurring.

i tried to use the same attributes of the retrieved item, and even remove them from the payload but it always shows this list of errors, i checked on the docs and there is nothing about this.

Note: I tried some other products that are tracked, and i could change them, and others not, i tried using only Name to be changed and the same issue, I can edit all items on Xero interface.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something in the payload is not correct. Please can you raise a case with Xero Support [here](https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support) and include your client id and the date and time (and timezone) for the error.

Comment: I submitted a case to them, the payload is good, i tried some other tracked items and i could edit them with the same payload format (i tried a payload of Name only and didn't work with items with this issue)